# How can I create a script which triggers an email based on a date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

again Im not very well skilled in google scripts however I have had a lot of support through here so any guidance would be appreciated.

I would like to be able to remind a recipient a process is due for an update by a certain date. Ideally would like it where a reminder is sent 1 month before then again 1 week before the process is due for review.

I would like to be able to send a generic email which the only variables would be the recipients name, email address, due date and the name of the process.

Any ideas on how I could do this or any tutorials that would work. I have attached the link to the google sheet which the emails should be triggered off

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qw8WefbVkS-AQXi1CcZ0z2CL-P0oNSZYqeT40oVF6go/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In terms of a generic email I would like something like 

"Hello {{Name}}

The process for {{Process Name}} is due to review on {{Due Date}}

Please review the content and contact the process team before its due date if amendments are required."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I let you customize the text ...

```
function reminder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
    if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+7*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+5*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][6]!=''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'reminder ... week', 
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][1]+' The process for '+data[i][0]+' is due to review on '+data[i][4]+' Please review the content and contact the process team before its due date if amendments are required'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,7).setValue('sent')
    }
    else if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+30*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+28*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][5]!=''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'reminer ... month', 
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][1]+' The process for '+data[i][0]+' is due to review on '+data[i][4]+' Please review the content and contact the process team before its due date if amendments are required'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,6).setValue('sent')
    }
  }
}
```

Then put a trigger on a daily basis

Comment: Thank you this all seems to work and have put in my amended wording. However is it possible to add variables into the text Im sending via email. As seen below can the script pull things from the sheet e.g Name and Process Name and send this via email 

Hello {{Name}} The process for {{Process Name}} is due to review on {{Due Date}} Please review the content and contact the process team before its due date if amendments are required

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can modify the texts as you wish.

Comment: Thanks I can confirm this has worked I appreciate all the support on this I do have 2 more questions. 

1. When the email is being issued it is stating the date due and also including the time e.g "Thu Jan 06 2022 19:00:00 GMT (Eastern Standard Time)". Is there a way for it to only show the date and not the time? 

2. The emails are currently being generated once I input "SENT" then press run on the script. Can this be automated so it sends this automatically. I may have set up the trigger incorrectly.

Comment: in htmlbody, replace `data[i][4]` by `Utilities.formatDate(data[i][4], "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy") `

Comment: `sent` is generated by the script itself to avoid repetitive emails. Just trigger the function to run once a day at any time (whichever you choose)

Comment: Thanks, so I shouldn't need to input Sent then hit run it should run automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239958/discussion-between-manraj-sidhu-and-mike-steelson).